# Start new Activity from JNI

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-ndk

I would like use this code from JNI

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
```

So far, i wrote the next code but i'm getting error from the constructor with params i guess ?

```
jclass intentClass = env->FindClass("android/content/Intent");
jstring actionString =env->NewStringUTF("com.test.package.TestActivity");
jmethodID newIntent = env->GetMethodID(intentClass, "<init>", "(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent");
jobject intent = env->NewObject(intentClass,newIntent,context,actionString);
jclass activityClass = env->FindClass("android/app/Activity");
jmethodID startActivity = env->GetMethodID(activityClass,"startActivity", "(Landroid/content/Intent;)V");
env->CallVoidMethod( intent, startActivity);
```

The error:

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewObjectV called with pending
>   exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method
>   "Landroid/content/Intent;.(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent"

The context and actionString params are OK and used somewhere else in code, so could you please help me I'm not familiar with JNI, if i use it , its for security reasons and try to avoid pirac.

Thanks

Comment: The `<init>` methods typically have a `void` return type.

Comment: Thanks Michael but i tried that too previously and i got same error :JNI NewObjectV called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Landroid/content/Intent;.<init>(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)V"

Comment: Well, where did you find that `Intent` has a constructor that takes `Context, String`? I don't see any such constructor in the documentation.

Comment: You are right, i replace the string by Ljava/lang/Class , so now how can i pass this class "com.test.package.TestActivity"  by a jclass ? like env->FindClass("com/test/package/TestActivity") ?

Comment: Yes.That looks about right.

Comment: I'm getting this error :JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale WeakGlobal 0x748b307d9f  (index 1219692505 in a table of size 109)   JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted weak global reference 0x748b307d9f

Comment: Then you need to figure out which line of code is causing that error, and work backwards to verify every relevant step you did leading up to the line.

Comment: It's the last line who makes the crash :     env->CallVoidMethod( intent,startActivity);
Thanks for your time was really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Michael :
The answer working for what i want to do with jobject context from parameter  function  :

```
   jclass native_context = env->GetObjectClass(context);
    jclass intentClass = env->FindClass("android/content/Intent");
    jclass actionString = env->FindClass("yourPackage/YourActivity");
    jmethodID newIntent = env->GetMethodID(intentClass, "<init>", "(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/Class;)V");
    jobject intent = env->NewObject(intentClass,newIntent,context,actionString);
    jmethodID methodFlag = env->GetMethodID(intentClass, "setFlags", "(I)Landroid/content/Intent;");
    jobject intentActivity = env->CallObjectMethod(intent, methodFlag, 268435456 );
    jmethodID startActivityMethodId = env->GetMethodID(native_context, "startActivity", "(Landroid/content/Intent;)V");
    env->CallVoidMethod(context, startActivityMethodId, intentActivity);
```